# Swift - How to check all sub sets and return true if each item is present in list

Tags: swift, set

I require help in an approach to check through sets within a set where each sub-set must be present in the list before returning true.

```
init(){ 
    let list1 : Set<Int> = [1,2] 
    let list2 : Set<Int> = [3,4] 
    let list3 : Set<Int> = [5,6,7] 
    let list4 : Set<Int> = [8,9]

    listGroups = [list1,list2,list3,list4] 
}

func checklist(_ list: [Numbers]) -> Bool { 
    //I want to check that each sub set(list1-list4) elements exist 
    //E.G. if list contains 2, 3, 7, 8 it will return true 
    //and if list contain 1, 4, 7, freturn false as it doesn't contain a  
    //number from each set 
}
```

I dont necessarily want it done for me but an explanation on how to approach and why you suggest this approach.

I've kept the code example simple but if you need more just let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for a an algorithm or for a simple more practical solution done by Swift’s features ?

Comment: I've updated the Question above, but in summary i want a way to check that the Numbers list passed through contain an id within list1, list2, list3 and list4 before it will return true and if there is only 3 out of 4 then return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Swift 4.2

You should check if each `list` of `listGroups` contains at least one `Int` from `numbers` array. If doesn't, return `false`. If does, return `true`. For this you can use `allSatisfy` method

```
func checklist(_ numbers: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return listGroups.allSatisfy { $0.contains(where: numbers.contains) }
}
```

### Older versions

For older versions of Swift you can create for each loop which does the similar, but just on multiple lines

```
func checklist(_ numbers: [Int]) -> Bool {

    for list in listGroups {
        if !list.contains(where: numbers.contains) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified with (the new) `allSatisfy()` method of sequences.

Comment: @MartinR thank you. I didn't know about this method. I added this solution to my answer.

Comment: would this method also work if i was to pass through a list of objects which each element contains "id, name, price" for example

Comment: yes, but you would have to make your custom object Codable.

Comment: I've taken a look and while the .allSatisfy is only present in version 10+ i am only able to use 9.4.1.

I've ran into an issue where if i am using an element which contains more that one piece of information such as "item1: id, name, price" how do i take just the id of that element and check against the listGroups untill i have 4 items which each correspond to an id in each of the sub-sets